# I incorrectly encoded utf-8, and I can't seem to fix it

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-requests

I've built a basic scraper that takes a page and writes it to a txt file. The important code is:

```
web_page = requests.get(url)

with open(filename) as file:
        file.write(str(web_page.content))
```

but my resulting text files contained lots of incorrect characters like \xe2\x80\x9c

I've done a lot of reading, and have found three ways I could have avoided this issue, but the problem is that I've already scraped a huge amount of data that I don't want do again.

I tried three ways that managed to stop the issue happening:

- Specifying the encoding, i.e. str(site_2.content, "utf-8"). It's strange that this works, since my sys.getdefaultencoding() is utf-8 anyway
- I could have used web_page.text instead of web_page.content
- I can decode it immediately with site_2.content.decode('utf-8')

But none of these work on my downloaded files.

Comment: Can't you just open your downloaded file with `open('yourfile.txt', encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: Nope, open(filename, encoding='UTF_8').read() doesn't fix it.

Comment: If it helps, no matter how I import the file, it ends up starting with 'b\' However, when I open it in TextEdit it starts with just b' and this might have something to do with it because all my methods above that work, start off with b'. In other words, web_page.content starts with a b' and web_page.content.decode("utf-8") works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's python's string representation of a `bytes` object, not utf-8. `web_page.content` is the binary content of the web page before `requests` has decoded it into a string. `str(...)` created a python string representation of the binary data (non-ascii bytes are escaped and the whole thing is wrapped in `b'...'`) which you wrote to the file. All you have to do is reverse the process by having python parse the string back into binary data and saving that.

```
import ast
content = open('test.html').read()
open('test.html.fixed', 'wb').write(ast.literal_eval(content))
```

In the future you can either have requests decode the file for you or save the binary:

```
web_page = requests.get(url)

# write binary if you expect a future html or xml processor to
# read it
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(web_page.content)

# ---- or ---- write text if you expect humans to read it
with open(filename) as file:
    file.write(web_page.text)
```